# Color ramp banding in PDFKit when exporting Raster image Inset to PDF

Tags: graphics, export, image, mac-os-x, pdf-format

Here I produce a `Raster` image with large uniformly colored rectangles and put it in an `Inset`:

```
With[{n = 5},
 Graphics[Inset[
   Graphics[Raster[
     {Map[
       List @@ ColorConvert[ColorData["LakeColors"][#], 
          RGBColor] &, (Range[n - 1] - 1)/(n - 2)]}
     ]],
   Automatic, Automatic, {.45, .5}
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Raster]

Now export this to `PDF`:

```
Export["p.pdf", %]
```

[image: ramp artefacts]

The uniform regions have been replaced by a series of discrete bands that seem to try an interpolate between the rectangles. This happens if I choose fewer rectangles too (e.g., `n = 3`).

If I generate the same thing *without* using `Raster`, the exported `PDF` looks fine - e.g., try this:

```
With[{n = 5},
 Graphics[Inset[
   Graphics[
    MapIndexed[{ColorData["LakeColors"][#], 
       Translate[Rectangle[], {#2[[1]], 0}]} &, (Range[n - 1] - 
        1)/(n - 2)]
    ]
   ,
   Automatic, Automatic, {.45, .5}
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

So it's the conversion of the rasterized image in `Export` that's responsible for this effect. Interestingly, one can work around this (on Mac) by selecting the graphic, going to `Edit > Copy As > PDF` and pasting the result into `Preview`.

Although I have some workarounds now, it still seems mysterious to me why this banding effect happens with `Raster`. And it would of course be nice if someone knew **how to use `Raster` in an `Inset` inside a `Graphics` without triggering the effect** that causes the blocks of the raster to lose their uniform color.

Also - the arguments to `Inset` can be left out (in particular the scaling `{.45, .5}`). But it seemed to me that this problem didn't always happen with `Raster`, and that it probably has something to do with the size of the bitmap being scaled up relative to some assumed coordinate system used in `Export`.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that this happens on Mac.The problem is Preview. If you load the file in Adobe Reader you will see the PDF graphic as expected.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this problem too on both Mathematica and MATLAB outputs, and as Matariki said, it's due to Preview. The PDF/EPS files look fine when viewed with Adobe Reader or GhostView

Comment: @Matariki Thanks for the pointer - I guess this means it's Mac specific. Then I'll probably have a look at the `PDF` source and see if I can come up with a fix along the lines of the `MediaBox` replacement I did on [this page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/PreviewLeopard.html) - it didn't occur to me that I'd have to revisit that in this context...

Comment: @Jens I don't know if it is Mac specific but more Preview specific as the effect is not visible using PDF Reader on the Mac. This might have to do with OSX PDF rendering engine. I never looked into it myself. I couldn't observe the effect on Windows but there I used PDF Reader as the default.

Comment: @Matariki Yes indeed - it's WebKit specific. ghostscript and Inkscape work perfectly with the file. I meanwhile figured out a good work-around: apply `ColorConvert[..., "CMYK"]` to the `Graphics[Raster[...]]` expression, and the output looks fine. I want to try and see if one can do even better, though...

Comment: Perhaps all `Raster` objects are exported to PDFs as images (or in a format that suggests that they are images).  For images, especially smooth tone ones like photos, it does make sense to interpolate when rescaling them.  So perhaps this behaviour of Preview isn't technically incorrect.  But all of this is just a guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue seems to affect all `PDFKit` based viewers on OS X, but it doesn't appear to point to anything intrinsically wrong with *Mathematica*'s `PDF` export. A work-around that allows you to view the exported `PDF` without color bands in `PDFKit` viewers such as `Preview` would be to use the following command when creating the `PDF` in *Mathematica*:

```
Export["py.pdf", 
 p /. Graphics[Raster[i__]] :> 
   Image@Graphics[Raster[i]]]
```

Alternatively, if you know exactly where the `Raster` is being created, you may as well do the conversion immediately at that point. Then my example code above would have to be modified as follows:

```
With[{n = 5},
 Graphics[Inset[
   Image@Graphics[Raster[
      {Map[
        List @@ ColorConvert[ColorData["LakeColors"][#], 
           RGBColor] &, (Range[n - 1] - 1)/(n - 2)]}
      ]]]
  ]
 ]
```

After doing this, I see no more trace of the discrete bands.

**Edit** Originally I had inserted `ColorConvert` but then realized it's simply the conversion to `Image` that is required to make it work.

**Edit 2**

To make this more generally applicable: *whenever* your exported `PDF` shows banding in gradients, you could try to export the plot (let's call it `plot`) using this command:

```
Export["plot.pdf", plot /. Raster[i__] :>
 Raster@ImageData@Image@Graphics[Raster[i]]]
```

**Edit 3**

This is an old post, but in the meantime I encountered similar issues in many other contexts and came up with a different work-around which also applies here:

```
rasterTrick[plot_] := 
 Show[plot, 
  Prolog -> {Opacity[0], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {.1, 0}, {.1, .1}}]}]

Export["p.pdf", plot // rasterTrick]
```

The function `rasterTrick` was recently useful in answering this question (where you can also find a link to further explanations of how it works): [Export MatrixPlot graphics to PDF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58262/245)

Comment: Well done, Jens. Dafuer gibt's +1

Comment: @Matariki And thanks for your help finding the culprit!