# Export MatrixPlot graphics to PDF

Tags: export, pdf-format

I am trying to export a plot generated by `MatrixPlot` to PDF but am having problems with the way the exported PDF is rendered.

```
  mPlot = MatrixPlot[length, 
  Epilog -> {Cyan, 
    MapIndexed[If[#1 != 0, Text[#1, Reverse[#2 - 1/2]]] &, 
     Reverse[number], {2}]}, Mesh -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Table[i, {i, 9}], 
     MapIndexed[{First[#2], regionCodes[[#1]]} &, 
      Table[i, {i, 9}]]}, {Table[i, {i, 9}], 
     MapIndexed[{First[#2], Rotate[regionCodes[[#1]], 90 Degree]} &, 
      Table[i, {i, 9}]]}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {Min[length], Max[length]}]
```

The matrices `length` (plotted as shades of gray in the figure below), `number` (shown as the cyan numbers in the figure below), and `regionCodes` have the following values

```
length = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.079774, 0.0545131, 
   0.0484267, 0.0614324, 0.0627509, 0.0572262, 0.0424639, 0}, {0, 0, 
   0.0600802, 0.100418, 0.0615561, 0.0737833, 0.0732888, 0.0624553, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0.0740108, 0.0559982, 0.0666054, 0.0749018, 
   0.0493431, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0774839, 0.0554172, 0.0564699, 
   0.0491287, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0798436, 0.0643044, 0.0606039, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.107009, 0.0713126, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0.0951722, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
number = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 37, 53, 21, 778, 1064, 228,
    15, 0}, {0, 0, 27, 40, 761, 1164, 272, 21, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 7, 331, 
   507, 125, 9, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 5935, 12430, 2917, 245, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 10665, 4323, 393, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 664, 90, 0}, {0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
regionCodes = {"New England", "Middle Atlantic", "East North Central",
   "West North Central", "South Atlantic", "East South Central", 
  "West South Central", "Mountain", "Pacific"}
```

This is `length//MatrixForm`

[image]

And this is `number//MatrixForm`

[image]

The plot looks like this when shown in Mathematica
[image]

But the exported PDF is rendered as follows (shown in OS X Preview)
[image]

There is a lot of shading and (and anti-aliasing?) going on (it shouldn't!). The only solution I have come up with is to rasterize the plot before exporting it. It does the job, but I don't consider it very elegant.

```
Export["regionIBD_MatrixPlot.pdf", Rasterize[mPlot, ImageResolution -> 600], ImageSize -> Full]
```

The funny thing is that if I export it as TIFF, it renders correctly. Is there a way to export the plot as a vector graphics and not as a bitmap?

Comment: Are you using version 10? There have been other complaints about PDF export issues in v10 so this may be part of a larger problem. I couldn't test it in v9 since some definitions are not present in the post.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am using version 10. I'll look up other comments, in case there are already workarounds posted.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/exporting-graphics-to-pdf-huge-file) there are some nice strategies concerning `vectors for simple graphics` and/or `high resolution rasterized image`. And please post code **and** data, if people are willing to help this is very **helpful**.

Comment: Thanks @Lou. I've already read that thread. The method suggested there in the first answer (by @Heike) involves rasterizing the image, although when I used `"AllowRasterization" -> True`, it produced the same shaded(!) PDF, hence my use of `Rasterize[]`.

Oh, and I have posted code and data! Is it not readable? Did I use an incorrect format?

Comment: Code is ok, but if I'm not mistaken regionCodes, length and number can not be copied, are not as data but as image uploaded. People will not write off your data.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, you're right...I'll fix that.

Comment: In the meantime, this strategy can help you [Link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11842/efficient-export-of-complex-graphics-to-pdf?rq=1)

Comment: exporting to EPS and using `epstopdf` produced the same old shaded PDF.

Comment: duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11273/pdf-exports-of-arrayplots-are-fuzzy-os-x/11283#11283 ?

Comment: ^ more or less! it's the same problem (fuzziness in OS X Preview), but I also do see the same problem in Adobe Reader, and changing Rendering options there hasn't fixed it for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To long for a comment, but looks great on "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)"
with AR, Preview and Skim. Shut-down and restart your system and try with an alternative viewer ...

[image]

**Edit**

@Jens response is fantastic, right? The procedure improves the resolution dramatically and even reduced the size.

[image]

I was able to test both algorithms on iMac & MacBookRetina (Home) and iMac (work). No difference, still the same results. The PDF's I opened on W7 & W8 with AR without significant differences between Mac and W be seen.

I am also "R" user and therefore use X11 and Cairo. On my Mac the Cairo Engine is the PDF Creator (I guess?). I wanted to share this information with the community.

Maybe this Information leads to a new question with even better answers.

Comment: Oh, cool! Your answer made me think that maybe the problem is indeed in Preview, so I looked at its Preferences and in the PDF tab, there is an option "Smooth test and line art"; unchecking it fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are most welcome, to check the settings and preferences is always a good thing :)

Comment: True! I just tried Adobe Acrobat, and it does the same weird smoothing/shading (and I haven't been able to fix it yet!).

Comment: @darXider You should upvote Lou's answer :)

Comment: i tried, really, but i have less than 15 reputations, and it prevented me! sorry, but i'm only a n00b here ;)

Comment: @darXider Oh oops. No big deal, I just thought maybe you had forgotten. Welcome to the site.

Comment: ok! upvoted now. thanks Lou and @mfvonh.

Comment: @Lou: just to double-check! did you have to turn off any anti-aliasing/smoothing options in Skim and/or Adobe Reader (assuming that's what you meant by "AR" in your answer)? i tried Skim as well, and i had to turn off that option. in the figure you posted, is that option on or off?

Answer (score 7):

I see this problem too, and I found it is fixed in Skim and Preview by using this function:

```
rasterTrick[plot_] := 
 Show[plot, 
  Prolog -> {Opacity[0], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {.1, 0}, {.1, .1}}]}]

Export["regionIBD_MatrixPlot1.pdf", mPlot // rasterTrick]
```

The convenience function `rasterTrick` is from my answer to [Avoiding grid lines inside filled area in RegionPlot exported as PDF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18631/245).

Comment: fantastic! it fixes things in Preview, Skim, and Adobe Reader.

Comment: I tend to testify this answer is Jens-sastic.

Comment: @Lou New dictionary item - "jens-sastic (adj.): awkward and painful solution to a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place"

Comment: I just remembered that I had asked a closely related question myself in 2012, and that this answer also applies there: [Color ramp banding in PDFKit when exporting Raster image Inset to PDF](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8118/245).

Comment: Your solution works for me as well, but the exported graphic is still a bit more fuzzy than if I save it as png for example. Is there a way to improve the level of fuzzyness based on your code (even if it increases the size of the pdf)?

Answer (score 5):

A similar problem is being discussed in [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11273/pdf-exports-of-arrayplots-are-fuzzy-os-x/66026#66026). I'll copy my method of going around it here, in case someone stumbles on this thread through searches.

> I have been saving a file wit MatrixPlot (using Save As...-> PDF), and
>   have encountered a similar problem.
>
> Turns out, MatrixPlot (and similar) data is being exported as a
>   bitmap, which gets blurred in Adobe Reader 9 (which I have), even if
>   "Smooth line art" and "Smooth images" is unchecked in preferences. The
>   PDF showed fine in Okular, but that is probably just the lack of
>   smoothing in that viewer.
>
> I have found the solution on [Inkscape
>   forums](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=15829). Open
>   the PDF file in a text editor, and locate the following line:
>
> > /Interpolate true
>
> Change it to the following:
>
> > /Interpolate false
>
> Et voilà! The problem is solved, and the PDF shows fine in Adobe
>   Reader, without blurring.

Comment: thanks for the information! that's very useful.