# ContourPlot colors changing in pdf Export

Tags: plotting, export

It has happened to me that when I export certain `ContourPlot` outputs, the colours in the legend appear different in the legend. See below the code and the two pictures (on the left the notebook file, on the right the exported pdf). What is happening?

```
ρ[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
Θ[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y];

f[x_, y_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{1/2 + 
      0.000051502449550377714*t*BesselK[0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/10] - 
      BesselK[0, 
        Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/10]/(2*
         BesselK[0, 1/10]) + ((0.5 - 0.00012500000000000003*t)*
         BesselK[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/10]*Cos[0. + ArcTan[x, y]])/(2*
         BesselK[1, 1/10]), 
     x^2 + y^2 >= 
      1}, {((0.5 - 0.00012500000000000003*t)*
        BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/10]*Cos[0. + ArcTan[x, y]])/(2*
        BesselJ[1, 1/10]), 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1}}, 0];
g[x_, y_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{((0.5 - 0.0025000000000000005*t)*
        Sin[0. + ArcTan[x, y]])/(2*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]), 
     x^2 + y^2 >= 
      1}, {((0.5 - 0.0025000000000000005*t)*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]*
        Sin[0. + ArcTan[x, y]])/2, 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1}}, 0];

x0=0;L=1;a=1;Ly=L;y0=0;

cs2[t_] :=  ContourPlot[(2 f[x, y, t]^2 + 
 2 g[ρ[x, y], Θ[x, y], t]^2)^(1/2), {x, -L + x0, L + x0}, {y, -L + y0, L + y0},    PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {Full, Full, {0, 0.5}},    PlotPoints -> 30,    ColorFunction -> ({Opacity[0.6],       ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#]} &), Contours -> 100,    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0.01 < x^2  + y^2 < a^2],    Exclusions -> None];

Export["inner.pdf",cs2[0]]
```

[image][image]

Comment: What version are you using?  When I run your code in either 10.3 or 11.0, I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/URcVw.png).  Also, include your operating system, as that may be important for PDF exporting.  You don't have `y0` defined, but based on your plot range in the images I set it to the same value as x0.

Comment: Also, what PDF viewer are you using?  Can you upload a PDF?

Comment: I am on Mac OSX, and I have tried Skim and Preview, and both give the same colors. Version 10.0.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on a much simpler contour plot, like `ContourPlot[Sin[x + y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}.....` - it makes it easier to nail down what is happening if we can use a simpler example.  Also, what happens if you use `(Directive[Opacity[0.5], ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#]] &)` for your `ColorFunction` instead?

Comment: Same problem with this code: `cs2 = ContourPlot[x + y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {Full, Full, {0, 0.5}}, 
   PlotPoints -> 30, 
   ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[0.5], 
       ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#]] &), Contours -> 100, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0.01 < x^2 + y^2 < a^2], 
   Exclusions -> None, ImageSize -> Large];`

Comment: Have a look [Export MatrixPlot graphics to PDF](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58241/export-matrixplot-graphics-to-pdf) and check your viewer at preferences

Comment: I have tried many things but none has worked, in terms of changing preferences in the pdf viewers. It still doesn't give the right colours in Skim nor in Preview...