# Vectorize pixel SphericalPlot

Tags: export, image-processing

I have a question about Mathematica images exporting. I have created 3d (SpericalPlot) with coloring function on it and then exported it to pdf. Is there any possibility to make more vector graphics look - boundary pixels between white background and other elements ?

Part of the code:

```
axes[x_, y_, z_, a_] := 
Graphics3D[
Join[{Red, Arrowheads[a], 
Arrow[Tube[#, 0.015]]} & /@ {{{-x, 0, 0}, {x, 0, 0}}, {{0, -y, 0}, {0, y, 0}}, {{0, 0,-z}, {0, 0, z}}}, 
{Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(x\)]\)", 18, Bold, Black], {1.1*x, 0.1*y, 0.1*z}], 
Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(y\)]\)", 18, Bold, Black], {0.1 *x, 1.1*y,0.1*z}], 
Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(z\)]\)", 18, Bold, Black], {0.1*x, 0.1*y, 1.1*z}]}]];
```

Ploting:

```
Show[SphericalPlot3D[1, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r}, 
ColorData["DarkRainbow"][QMap[\[Theta], \[Phi], data]/MaxQ]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> False, Axes -> False, 
PlotPoints -> 200, ImageSize -> {350, 350}, Boxed -> False, 
ViewPoint -> {-3, 0, 0}, ViewAngle -> 0.37], 
axes[1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 0.03], 
PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}];
```

Saving:

```
Export["im.pdf", Style[Show[p3, Prolog -> {Opacity[0], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
Polygon[{{0, 0}, {.1, 0}, {.1, .1}}]}], Antialiasing -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica 3d image]

Comment: Under Preferences -> Appearance -> Graphics, is antialiasing set to "highest quality"?

Comment: You could try the function `rasterTrick` from my [answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8121/245). If that doesn't work, please explain the issue in more detail with some sample code.

Comment: I have already used Your trick to get rid of meshing lines :)

Comment: I've inserted part of the code in my question - antialiasing does not work

Comment: I used ImageResolution set to 1500 and it is better, but if I want higher e.g. 1800 my Mathematica 10 crashes on Windows 7 :(

Comment: The code isn't self-contained, so it doesn't produce an image. But how about replacing `Antialiasing -> True` with `Magnification -> 2` in the `Style` command?

Comment: Have you considered PNG instead of PDF?  For `Tube`,  `Cone` etc.,  PDF export is a very mixed bag,  and file sizes are sometimes gigantic.

Comment: Magnification and .png is worser than pdf even for huge ImageResolution. I wonder why the DensityPlot on the sphere is smooth (without any pixels) by only edges of the sphere and arrows together with text are so bad?

Comment: Other way around - this 3d spherical plot from given ViewVector looks like 2d plot. Maybe there is a way to make such projection 2d and there would be no problem with vector graphics. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

As I said in the comment, it's possible to get better results with the trick I used in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8121/245). I'm doing this in the `Export` command below. For the explanation, follow the link.

Here is a version of your code that produces an image:

```
axes[x_, y_, z_, a_] := 
  Graphics3D[
   Join[{Red, Arrowheads[a], 
       Arrow[Tube[#, 0.015]]} & /@ {{{-x, 0, 0}, {x, 0, 0}}, {{0, -y, 
        0}, {0, y, 0}}, {{0, 0, -z}, {0, 0, z}}}, {Text[
      Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(x\)]\)", 18, Bold, 
       Black], {1.1*x, 0.1*y, 0.1*z}], 
     Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(y\)]\)", 18, Bold, 
       Black], {0.1*x, 1.1*y, 0.1*z}], 
     Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(z\)]\)", 18, Bold, 
       Black], {0.1*x, 0.1*y, 1.1*z}]}]];

p3 = Show[
   SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    ColorFunction -> 
     Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, 
      ColorData["DarkRainbow"][.1]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    Mesh -> False, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 200, 
    ImageSize -> {350, 350}, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {-3, 0, 0}, 
    ViewAngle -> 0.37], axes[1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 0.03], 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}];

Export["im.pdf", 
 Style[Show[p3, 
   Prolog -> {Opacity[0], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {.1, 0}, {.1, .1}}]}], Magnification -> 2]]
```

In the `Style` command, I only specify `Magnification -> 2`. Now the PDF file looks like this on my screen:

[image: screenshot]

To compare with your screen shot, I zoomed in:

[image: zoomed]

You can increase the `Magnification` to get smooth appearance for larger zoom as well. The on-screen appearance will also depend on the PDF viewer. I used Preview on Mac OS X. For this to work, it's important to keep the `Prolog` in `Show` (which is what I call `rasterTrick` in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8121/245)) because otherwise the export won't be rasterized and the file will be huge.

As to the question whether the 3D graphics output `p3` can be converted to a smaller but 2D vector format, the answer is no: there is no built-in functionality for that.